# Print variable to console print an empty value

Tags: powershell

I wrote the following function in PowerShell and for some reason when I try to print variables to screen they print out empty (it execute the command form the variable so I know the value is passed) - why?

```
function Verify-Command-Dependency {
    Param($cmd, $name, $error)

    Try
    {
        $result = "$name dependency installed."
        Write-Host "$name"
        Invoke-Expression -Command "$cmd" -OutVariable out
        Write-Color -Text "[ ", "OK", " ] ", $result -Color White, Green, White, White
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Output $error
        Break
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure $name has a value?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to print variables to screen they print out empty"? How exactly you doing it?

Comment: How are you calling the function? What output do you expect? What output do you get? Which statement doesn't write the output you're expecting? `Write-Host`, `Write-Color` (which isn't a PowerShell builtin cmdlet), or `Write-Output`?

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns *Inside the function the output of Write-Host is piped to the return value of the caller.* No. Even with PowerShell v5 `Write-Host` output goes to the host console and nowhere else.